# Is it possible to avoid these three loops?

Tags: pandas, loops

I'm combining two dataset where I have to generate a specific value for each cell. My code has three loops inside each other. I tried to reduce them, but couldn't find a better alternative as long as I don't give up the value I want in the loop-2.

data source: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/hugomathien/soccer

```
'''dataset 1'''
    id  country_id  league_id   season  stage   date    match_api_id    home_team_api_id    away_team_api_id    home_team_goal  away_team_goal  home_player_1   home_player_2   home_player_3   home_player_4   home_player_5   home_player_6   home_player_7   home_player_8   home_player_9   home_player_10  home_player_11  away_player_1   away_player_2   away_player_3   away_player_4   away_player_5   away_player_6   away_player_7   away_player_8   away_player_9   away_player_10  away_player_11
145 146 1   1   2008/2009   24  2009    493017  8203    9987    2   1   38327.0 67950.0 67958.0 67959.0 37112.0 36393.0 148286.0    67898.0 164352.0    38801.0 26502.0 37937.0 38293.0 148313.0    104411.0    148314.0    37202.0 43158.0 9307.0  42153.0 32690.0 38782.0
153 154 1   1   2008/2009   25  2009    493025  9984    8342    1   3   36835.0 37047.0 37021.0 37051.0 104386.0    32863.0 37957.0 37909.0 38357.0 37065.0 78462.0 37990.0 21812.0 11736.0 37858.0 38366.0 37983.0 39578.0 38336.0 52280.0 27423.0 38440.0
155 156 1   1   2008/2009   25  2009    493027  8635    10000   2   0   34480.0 38388.0 26458.0 13423.0 38389.0 30949.0 38393.0 38253.0 38383.0 38778.0 37069.0 37900.0 37886.0 37903.0 37889.0 94030.0 37893.0 37981.0 131531.0    130027.0    38231.0 131530.0

'''dataset 2'''
    id  player_fifa_api_id  player_api_id   date    overall_rating  preferred_foot  attacking_work_rate defensive_work_rate crossing    finishing   heading_accuracy    short_passing   volleys dribbling   curve   free_kick_accuracy  long_passing    ball_control    acceleration    sprint_speed    agility reactions   balance shot_power  jumping stamina strength    long_shots  aggression  interceptions   positioning vision  penalties   marking standing_tackle sliding_tackle
0   1   218353  505942  2016    67.0    right   medium  medium  49.0    44.0    71.0    61.0    44.0    51.0    45.0    39.0    64.0    49.0    60.0    64.0    59.0    47.0    65.0    55.0    58.0    54.0    76.0    35.0    71.0    70.0    45.0    54.0    48.0    65.0    69.0    69.0
1   2   218353  505942  2015    67.0    right   medium  medium  49.0    44.0    71.0    61.0    44.0    51.0    45.0    39.0    64.0    49.0    60.0    64.0    59.0    47.0    65.0    55.0    58.0    54.0    76.0    35.0    71.0    70.0    45.0    54.0    48.0    65.0    69.0    69.0
2   3   218353  505942  2015    62.0    right   medium  medium  49.0    44.0    71.0    61.0    44.0    51.0    45.0    39.0    64.0    49.0    60.0    64.0    59.0    47.0    65.0    55.0    58.0    54.0    76.0    35.0    63.0    41.0    45.0    54.0    48.0    65.0    66.0    69.0


'''generate a column list for 11 players'''
home_player_col = []
for i in range(1,12):
    home_player_col.append('home_player_' + str(i))

'''function to get a date from a list that's closest to a target date'''
def get_closest_date(date, date_list):
    return date_list[min(range(len(date_list)), key = lambda i: abs(date_list[i]-date))]

'''the function with two loops'''
def add_home_attribute(df, attribute):
    
    match_all = {}    
    '''loop-1: loop each row because I need value of row.date for loop-2'''
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        row = pd.Series(row)
        match_detail = {}
        '''create key 'match_api_id' for later dataframe merge'''
        match_detail['match_api_id'] = row.match_api_id
        rating_list = []
        '''loop-2: loop through 11 home players'''
        for col in home_player_col:
            player_id = row[col]
            '''find the date from player dataset that is closest to the match date'''
            date = get_closest_date(row.date, list(player_detail[player_detail.player_api_id == player_id].date))
            '''each player has multiple ratings in one year, so I average them'''
            rating_list.append(player_detail[(player_detail.player_api_id == player_id) & (
                player_detail.date == date)][attribute].mean())
        '''average the rating of all 11 players'''
        match_detail['home_'+attribute] = sum(rating_list)/len(rating_list)
        match_all[index] = match_detail
    
    '''get a dataframe that has home team's average rating in all 21,000 matches'''
    df_attr = pd.DataFrame(match_all).T
    
    return df_attr

'''loop-3: loop through multiple attributes'''
for attr in attr_list:
    home_attr = add_home_attribute(matches, attr)
    away_attr = add_away_attribute(matches, attr)
    matches_new = matches_new.merge(home_attr, on='match_api_id').merge(away_attr, on='match_api_id')
```

The complete final result has columns like this:

```
match_api_id    home_team_goal  away_team_goal  home_overall_rating away_overall_rating home_crossing   away_crossing   home_finishing  away_finishing  home_long_passing   ... home_sprint_speed   away_sprint_speed   home_agility    away_agility    home_vision away_vision home_standing_tackle    away_standing_tackle    home_sliding_tackle away_sliding_tackle
0   493017  2   1   61.818182   66.045455   49.863636   55.318182   48.090909   50.227273   53.636364   ... 63.454545   68.454545   NaN 65.363636   NaN 60.818182   48.272727   47.545455   NaN 49.272727
1   493025  1   3   66.136364   68.818182   57.181818   58.318182   55.954545   56.590909   61.590909   ... 68.181818   70.227273   65.272727   63.818182   68.181818   67.545455   49.000000   49.772727   49.818182   46.909091
2   493027  2   0   70.954545   63.545455   58.818182   52.090909   51.500000   44.454545   64.409091   ... 68.909091   66.272727   63.727273   64.363636   68.636364   66.000000   58.636364   49.772727   57.090909   51.000000
3   493034  2   1   62.181818   70.954545   49.409091   56.818182   49.500000   50.318182   52.545455   ... 64.136364   69.727273   59.454545   63.454545   61.727273   64.545455   47.954545   58.454545   53.454545   56.727273
4   493040  0   0   64.136364   61.909091   53.727273   48.454545   44.818182   44.863636   57.454545   ... 66.681818   63.545455   65.454545   NaN 66.181818   NaN 50.409091   47.681818   51.818182   NaN
```

The code works but the was super slow. I hope to learn how to avoid writing loop in loop. Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you edit your question and post sample input (small) and expected output (as text - so we can copy and paste it)?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes, just done. The columns didn't align but hopefully it tells the general story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may want to reshape your data.

For example you could use [`.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) on the match data to "collapse" the home/away player columns:

```
pd.wide_to_long(
   matches, 
   stubnames=["home_player", "away_player"], 
   i="id", 
   j="player_num", 
   sep="_"
).reset_index()
```

- `stubnames` are the prefixes of the columns you want to target, e.g. `home_player_1`, `away_player_1`
- `j` is the name of the new column that stores the suffix e.g. `_1`
- `sep` prevents the final `_` from being included in the result.

|  | id | player_num | match_api_id | home_team_goal | stage | home_team_api_id | away_team_goal | season | away_team_api_id | league_id | country_id | date | home_player | away_player |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 146 | 1 | 493017 | 2 | 24 | 8203 | 1 | 2008/2009 | 9987 | 1 | 1 | 2009 | 38327 | 37937 |
| 1 | 154 | 1 | 493025 | 1 | 25 | 9984 | 3 | 2008/2009 | 8342 | 1 | 1 | 2009 | 36835 | 37990 |

You could then use `.melt` to turn the `home_player`, `away_player` columns into a single `player` column:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(matches, stubnames=["home_player", "away_player"], i="id", j="player_num", sep="_")
   .reset_index()
   .rename(columns={"home_player": "home", "away_player": "away"})
   .melt(
      id_vars=[
         "id", "player_num", "match_api_id", "home_team_goal", "stage", 
         "home_team_api_id", "away_team_goal", "season", "away_team_api_id", 
         "league_id", "country_id", "date"], 
      var_name="player", 
      value_name="player_id")
)
```

|  | id | player_num | match_api_id | home_team_goal | stage | home_team_api_id | away_team_goal | season | away_team_api_id | league_id | country_id | date | player | player_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 146 | 1 | 493017 | 2 | 24 | 8203 | 1 | 2008/2009 | 9987 | 1 | 1 | 2009 | home | 38327 |
| 1 | 154 | 1 | 493025 | 1 | 25 | 9984 | 3 | 2008/2009 | 8342 | 1 | 1 | 2009 | home | 36835 |

From there it looks like you want to match the nearest date from the player data - which sounds like a [`.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) operation.

e.g.

```
pd.merge_asof(
   matches, 
   player_detail, 
   left_by="player_id",
   right_by="player_api_id",
   on="date",
   direction="nearest"
)
```

The `_by` parameters tell it to match these 2 columns for equality, and the `nearest` operation is performed on the `date` column.

This should give you everything together which would allow you to summarize the data without having to use for loops.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I rewrote it following your tips and it changed the code running time crazily. This is amazing!